# Search function stored procedure with multiple fields not returning expected results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table with 4 rows as follows:

```
| person_ID | FirstName | LastName | Phone      | Email                 |
+-----------+-----------+----------+------------+-----------------------+
| 1         | Ernaldo   | Chin     | 0000000000 | echin@blah.blah       |
| 2         | Esmerelda | Chin     | 1111111111 | echin@idk.org         |
| 1002      | Terry     | Bogard   | 2222222222 | tbogard@fatalfury.com |
| 1003      | Captain   | Falcon   | 3333333333 | cfalcon@fzero.com     |
```

When I run the following query the results are exactly as expected:
Query

```
DECLARE @firstname varchar(50) = NULL,
        @LastName varchar(50) = 'Chin',
        @person_ID int = null,
        @phone varchar(50) = null,
        @email varchar(50) = null

SELECT 
    [person_ID], [FirstName], [LastName], [Phone], [Email] 
FROM 
    [dbo].[Persons]
WHERE
    (@person_ID IS NULL OR person_ID = @person_ID)
    AND (@firstname IS NULL OR FirstName LIKE '%' + @firstname + '%')
    AND (@LastName IS NULL OR LastName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%')
```

Results

```
| person_ID | FirstName | LastName | Phone      | Email                 |
+-----------+-----------+----------+------------+-----------------------+
| 1         | Ernaldo   | Chin     | 0000000000 | echin@blah.blah       |
| 2         | Esmerelda | Chin     | 1111111111 | echin@idk.org         |
```

BUT I created a stored procedure as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Persons_Get]
    @person_ID int = NULL,
    @FirstName varchar = NULL,
    @LastName varchar = NULL,
    @Phone varchar = NULL,
    @Email varchar = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        [person_ID], [FirstName], [LastName], [Phone], [Email] 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Persons]
    WHERE
        (@person_ID IS NULL OR person_ID = @person_ID)
        AND (@Firstname IS NULL OR FirstName LIKE '%' + @Firstname + '%')
        AND (@LastName IS NULL OR LastName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%')
```

and execute it like this

```
EXEC Persons_Get @LastName = 'Chin'
```

I get these results

```
| person_ID | FirstName | LastName | Phone      | Email                 |
+-----------+-----------+----------+------------+-----------------------+
| 1         | Ernaldo   | Chin     | 0000000000 | echin@blah.blah       |
| 2         | Esmerelda | Chin     | 1111111111 | echin@idk.org         |
| 1003      | Captain   | Falcon   | 3333333333 | cfalcon@fzero.com     |
```

Am I going crazy here? I've already spent way too much time on this. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I might end up using dynamic SQL instead but I need to know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Looks like the latter one...)

Comment: Considering the use of the `dbo` (schema) this is clearly SQL Server, not MySQL. Please don't tag (random) other RDBMS, only tag the one you are really using.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) That Procedure is working **exactly** as it's supposed to, all of those surnames have a `c` in them: **C**hin, Fal**c**on.

Comment: `@FirstName varchar` how long is that? 1 character? Such catch-all queries are pretty bad for performance too. You'll have to add `WITH RECOMPILE` to avoid using inefficient execution plans. If you do that, you'll lose the performance benefit of using a stored procedure. It would be better if you constructed the appropriate query with an ORM on the client side

Comment: 1) Why you didn't set the length of the params (varchar) in the proc? 2) How did you pass the parameters to your SP?

Comment: Recommended reading: [#BackToBasics: An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) and [Catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)

Comment: If someone is looking for First Name = Sam, do you really want to include rows with Samatha and Kasam? THINK about your goal and your own assumptions that you embed in your code.

Comment: Thank you all. I am an idiot sandwich.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ***MUST*** at all times specify an **explicit length** for any `CHAR, NCHAR, VARCHAR, NVARCHAR` parameters! Otherwise they default to ***1*** character length!

Use this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Persons_Get]
    @person_ID int = NULL,
    @FirstName varchar(50) = NULL,
    @LastName varchar(50) = NULL,
    @Phone varchar(50) = NULL,
    @Email varchar(255) = NULL
AS
```

and your stored procedure will work **just fine**

Comment: @funkybunky: no need to hang - just *learn* ;-) And teach others who might end up making the same mistake ...